# How to commit changes to from GitHub actions as own GitHub account?

Tags: node.js, git, github, github-actions

I have a node.js project repo. I am trying to push updates in GitHub actions back to the repo. It works fine, but the commit author identity is not my GitHub identity. Eventhough I set username as as my GitHub username in the git config.

I tried using GitHub action checkout@v2 and also tried by using GitHub personal access token `hppts://${token}@github.com/...`

Comment: How do you set your username?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error, I figured out that what you want is linked to your email.

```
git config --global user.email "yatri@noreply.github.com"
```

Use the email you used to register for GitHub in place of the dummy email and it should work as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use workflow as follows

```
on:
  push:

jobs:
  ok:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Setup Git
        run: |
          git config --global user.name "Yatri"
          git config --global user.email "yatri@noreply.github.com"
      - name: Attempt Clone
        run: git clone https://${{secrets.PAT}}@github.com/yatri/private-repo.git
      - run: |
          cd private-repo
          git remote set-url origin https://${{secrets.PAT}}@github.com/yatri/private-repo.git
          git pull
          echo 'Hello' > test.txt
          git add .
          git commit -m 'test'
          git remote -v
          echo 'pushing changes...'
          git push origin main
```

Comment: `@noreply.github.com` -- does not work

Answer (score -1):

Interesting question. It is not possible to achieve what you want with GitHub PAT. Although it is linked to your GitHub account, it is identified as someone else other than you who is given the authority to perform some action on behalf of you.

Comment: Committer information and authorship has nothing to do with the PAT of GitHub.

Comment: Ok then how does github tag me with links to my GitHub account when I push commits to the repo?

Comment: Based on the committer/author information of the pushed commits. Maybe it detects the user account of the pushes too, but the question is about "committing changes" and the PAT is 100% unrelated to committing.

Comment: FYI, you can commit changes with PAT. Just set origin to https://${PAT}/user/repo

Comment: @yatri origin has nothing to do with committing. Remotes are only used during fetch and push. You can commit just fine without any remotes, an unreachable remote, or an unauthorized remote.